# Remove tuples from a list according to criteria

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to filter from a list all tuples that don't have specific elements. Specifically, suppose that:

```
mylist = [("sagap", "apple", "orange"), ("apple", "orange", "crazy"), ("crazy", "orange"), ("orange", "banana", "do", "does"), ("apple", "do", "does", "something", "response")]
```

I want to exclude/remove all those tuples in the list that don't contain `"apple"' and` "orange"' **within a tuple**

The expected result should be a new list with tuples as below:

```
mylist_new = [("sagap", "apple", "orange"), ("apple", "orange", "crazy") ]
```

I would appreciate your help. Please consider in my actual project the list has around 10000 tuples.

Ideally, I want to have something like:

```
list_of_items = ["apple, "orange"] 

search in my list which tuples have list_of_times and keep those in my list
```

**Please consider the number of items might not necessarily be just two, could be any large number of items to consider**

Comment: Have you tried with any code so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
mylist_new = [t for t in mylist if 'apple' in t and 'orange' in t]
```

Your example has some typos... changing it to

```
In [9]: mylist = [("sagap", "apple", "orange"), ("apple", "orange", "crazy"), ("crazy", "orange"), ("orange", "banana", "do", "does"), ("apple", "do", "does", "something", "response")]

In [10]: mylist_new = [t for t in mylist if 'apple' in t and 'orange' in t]

In [11]: mylist_new
Out[11]: [('sagap', 'apple', 'orange'), ('apple', 'orange', 'crazy')]
```

**UPDATE** OP updated question to allow ask for an arbitrary list of items

To accommodate this I would simply write a function that checks those in a loop

```py
def contains_items(t, list_of_items):
    for i in list_of_items:
        if i not in t:
           return False
    return True
```

Then my original answer would be

```
list_of_items = ["apple", "orange"] 
mylist_new = [t for t in mylist if contains_items(t, list_of_items)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate if you can help with the update. The reason that I don't like this solution very much is that the number of items I might need to look at might be more than 2 like 5 or 10 for example. I will update my question.

Comment: The solution doesn't change much you just need to write a function that still determines if a `tuple` meets your conditions, I've updated the response

Comment: For the modified 'arbitrary list of items' version, you can use `all(item in t for item in list_of_items)` - either as the `if` clause or as the body of `contains_items`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use filter function:

```
myList = [( "apple", "orange"), ("apple", "orange", "crazy"), ("crazy", "orange"), ("orange", "banana", "do", "does"), ("apple", "do", "does", "something", "response")]

def valid(t):
    return "apple" in t and "orange" in t

print(list(filter(valid, myList)))
```

its bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

Another oneliner:

```
myList = [( "apple", "orange"), ("apple", "orange", "crazy"), ("crazy", "orange"), ("orange", "banana", "do", "does"), ("apple", "do", "does", "something", "response")]

print(list(filter(lambda t: "apple" in t and "orange" in t, myList)))
```